# Laravel 8 - Property [xxx] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am here to show you "just another error".
I did not find any good source where is explained why I getting this error.

So, I have two database tables they are `withdraws` and `users`
My form works ideally, it will makes almost exactly what I want, create the record in `withdraws` table, but.. does not change funds in `users`

v-model and name parameter in form is "amount", but let me show you my function in that controller's code
`WithdrawController.php`:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getData();

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $this->withdrawService->create($data);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        $user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id);
        $user->funds -= $data['amount'];
        $user->save();

        Mail::to('')->send(new WithdrawRequestMail($user, $data['amount']));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: I see permutations of this query all the time on Stackoverflow, and I have no idea why... `User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->first()` or `User::find(auth()->user()->id)`, etc. I'm curious if there's a link; did you get this code from a tutorial somewhere? If yes, that tutorial should be updated to remove redundancy. If no (you wrote it), then it's a simple misunderstanding of how the `auth()` helper works, and no harm done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a query builder but have not executed any query yet:

```
$user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id);
```

You then try to use `$user` like it is Model. You would need to add `first()` to what you have to get the User:

```
$user = User::where('id', auth()->user()->id)->first();
```

Though you already have the user from the Auth system:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: Since you are searching with the primary key, you could also use: ```$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);```